# How to use an existing Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 13/14

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA. Normally I use `apply plugin: 'idea'` to generate the IDEA project files. With IDEA 12 I was used to work with the JetGradle tool view.

Now I updated to IDEA 13 and the JetGradle tool view is gone. When I use the old run configuration `gradle:run`, IDEA tells me:

```
Error running gradle:run:
Module 'X' is not backed by gradle.
```

How can I activate the gradle build in IDEA 13 without the tool view? I found this [tweet](https://twitter.com/CedricChampeau/status/407952417322708993) from Cédric Champeau, but was still not able to solve it. Do I have to turn my simple gradle project into a multi module project or what?

**Update**
With `File - Import Project ...` I can import the `build.gradle` file and than I can choose `View - Tool Windows - Gradle`, which was hidden before. Is this the  way to go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you state in your update is the correct way to go. The Gradle Plug-in received a lot of love in the IDEA 13 update and has changed a bit. An import of the Gradle build file is necessary. And as you have noted, the `JetGradle` tool window is now named simple `Gradle`

Comment: Is there a way to do this and not have the "build.gradle" directory as your root?  I have a lot of content below that directory.

Answer (score 7):

Tested with Gradle 1.9. In my opinion there are 2 issues:

- Issue 1: when using `gradlew idea` I expect to receive a valid IDEA project without the need to import it. There are discussions on the gradle forum, see [this Gradle forum post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/1_9rc3_idea_plugin_support_for_idea_13). In this [Jetbrains forum post](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504732#5504732) it is told that *there is no backward compatibility with IntelliJ 12 gradle projects at the moment*.
- Issue 2: With IDEA 12 it was possible to open the JetGradle View even if the current project was not a gradle projcet. But the view displayed the message "There is no linked Gradle project. You can Add one" and offered you the possibility to convert the project to an gradle project with a simple click. In IDEA 13 it is not possible to open the Gradle View when the current project is not a gradle project. I asked a question [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451349).

In the [Gradle forum post](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504732#5504732) mentioned above Peter Niederweiser stated:

*The preferred way of integrating with IDEA 13 is to use IDEA's Gradle import, without running gradle idea. (You should still apply the idea plugin though, and it's still important to apply it to allprojects {} rather than subprojects {} when dealing with multi-project builds.)*

So the answer from Mark Vedder is correct, altough I would have liked to have more information.

Comment: I have IDEA 13 and don't see `JetGradle` nor `Gradle` Tool Window anymore. I wanted to port a Maven project to Gradle without removing Maven until it runs in Jenkins as well. It's a pity...

Comment: Try to use the command line and execute `gradle init --type pom`. Than gradle should create the `build.gradle` from the Maven pom-file. Until everything is working you have to test via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when you initially import a gradle project into Idea, if you don't have all of your directories created yet, the gradle tool window vanishes while you are importing into Idea.  (It is there when the import starts, but at the end it disappears.)  However, if I manually build the project first (on a mac, >gradle clean build), and then go back to IDEA and import the project, the gradle tool window stays active.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: I had success with closing and reopening the project again. A popup bubble showed prompting me to setup a gradle project.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift +S) and then under the Modules, click "Import Module" and choose your `build.gradle` from the project file repo. It will make the module gradle aware and then you will also see the Gradle window

Comment: This works better for me than reopening or searching with double shift for 'import project' (they seem to have moved the option), which complained that I already had a project with the same name in the 
 same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the Import Project option if you cannot use the gradlew idea to produce the idea project